# Getting error when trying to build a static version of Qt

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt5

I've tried to solve this problem for a long time, now I really have to solve it (somehow) :)

I'm trying to build a static version of Qt 5, which obviously isn't as easy as I read in many tutorials (which obviously were not written for Qt 5, but previous versions).

I downloaded and installed Qt 5.0.1 for Windows 32-bit with MinGW 4.7. When trying to build a static version with

```
configure -static -release
```

and then

mingw32-make

I get the error:

```
kernel\qplatformopenglcontext.cpp: In constructor 'QPlatformOpenGLContextPrivate
::QPlatformOpenGLContextPrivate()':
kernel\qplatformopenglcontext.cpp:85:39: error: class 'QPlatformOpenGLContextPri
vate' does not have any field named 'context'
kernel\qplatformopenglcontext.cpp: At global scope:
kernel\qplatformopenglcontext.cpp:90:1: error: 'QPlatformOpenGLContext' does not
 name a type
kernel\qplatformopenglcontext.cpp:95:1: error: 'QPlatformOpenGLContext' does not
 name a type
kernel\qplatformopenglcontext.cpp:104:1: error: 'GLuint' does not name a type
kernel\qplatformopenglcontext.cpp:109:1: error: 'QOpenGLContext' does not name a
 type
kernel\qplatformopenglcontext.cpp:115:6: error: 'QPlatformOpenGLContext' has not
 been declared
kernel\qplatformopenglcontext.cpp:115:41: error: variable or field 'setContext'
declared void
kernel\qplatformopenglcontext.cpp:115:41: error: 'QOpenGLContext' was not declar
ed in this scope
kernel\qplatformopenglcontext.cpp:115:57: error: 'context' was not declared in t
his scope
kernel\qplatformopenglcontext.cpp:121:6: error: 'QPlatformOpenGLContext' has not
 been declared
Makefile.Release:22330: recipe for target '.obj/release_static/qplatformopenglco
ntext.o' failed
mingw32-make[3]: *** [.obj/release_static/qplatformopenglcontext.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/Src/qtbase/src/gui'
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [release] Error 2
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/Src/qtbase/src/gui'
Makefile:251: recipe for target 'sub-gui-make_first' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [sub-gui-make_first] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/Src/qtbase/src'
makefile:40: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first' failed
mingw32-make: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
```

Is anybody here who do this before with Qt 5?

Thank u very much in advance!

Comment: Does it build in shared mode? Looks quite unrelated to shared vs. static, to me.

Comment: how can i find out? I just installed QT on a new machine and want to compile existing projects in static mode.

Comment: Build it with configure -shared instead of -static